# Divide Mesh Into Separate Chunks

Tags: mesh

Looking for a way to automate splitting up a large mesh into smaller, 10k tri parts.

Currently I am having to take mesh and separate it by loose parts and from there, copy and pasting parts into another blender until I reach 10k tri's. Is there any other way to do this quicker?

Thanks,
Cameron

Comment: can you share Image that shows the problem?

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure it's very clear when you talk about "copy and pasting parts into another blender until I reach 10k tri's", could you please explain better?

Comment: Would it suffice to just go into edit mode, hover over a part of your object and press L, in the bottom right you can see how many vertices you have selected. Once you hit the sweet spot press p and separate selection.